# prototype ajax, undefined json after second setTimeout

Tags: ajax, settimeout

Having problem with prototype ajax and setTimeout. Here is my code shortened:

```
//new ajax request
....onComplete: function (transport) { //json as this -> array[$i].something
        var json = transport.responseJSON;
        var $i = 0;
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            SLOW();
        },
        500); //display every json[$i] with custom delay
        function SLOW() {
            $i++;
            if (json[$i].something !== null) { //insert in proper div id in the html document
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('document_div' + json[$i].something).innerHTML = json[$i].something_to_display;
                },
                500);
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('document_div' + json[$i].something).innerHTML = json[$i].something_to_display;
                },
                1000);...window.setTimeout(function () {
                    SLOW();
                },
                500);
            } else {
                //stop and continue
            }
```

Getting this error: `json[$i]` is undefined.

**EDIT: looks like i'm getting this error on second timeout, the first one changes the div correctly.**

Answer (score 0):

Done.

Solution was to re-var json again before using it in `setTimeout`.

```
var json_something = json[$i].something; //and so on...
var json_something_to_display = json[$i].something_to_display

 window.setTimeout(function() {     $('document_div'+json_something).innerHTML = json_something_to_display; }, 500);
```

Can somebody explain why this is needed? Why `var`ing json is not enough and it disapears somewhere after one `window.setTimeout` function?